# Sending messages to exclusive queue with AMQP/RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a number of machines that can do some actions. To initiate an action, I want to send a message to a queue named by the machine ID, "12345" for instance.

To avoid anyone else consuming these messages, the queue should be exclusive, I think.

But from my controller, I cannot assert the queue if it's declared as exclusive on the machine that consumes it. However, I can send to the queue by specifying its name, without asserting, but I guess that's bad practice?

The machine is listening for commands like this:

```
ch.assertQueue(machineID, {exclusive: true, durable: false}, function (err, q) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log("opened queue")
    ch.consume(q.queue, function (message) {
        console.log(message.content.toString())
    })
})
```

When I send to the queue, it will fail due to exclusive issues, at this line in the client:

```
ch.assertQueue(machineID, {})
```

But it will send the message if I comment the line above.

```
ch.sendToQueue(machineID, new Buffer(id.toString()))
```

What is the most elegant way to get around this?

Comment: Could you please publish the error message?

Comment: 405) RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue

Comment: Exclusive queue means that you cannot have more than one consumer. If you know that the queue should be always created by the consumer then it is not necessary to create it every time you want to send a message (it is better to create queue in the beginning). One possible problem is that the queue is defined with different parameters `{exclusive: true, durable: false}` and `{}` (by default exclusive is false) and usually it fails - the parameters should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create an exchange of type 'direct' and bind your queue to this exchange. So if you pass any message to this exchange then it will only be routed to that queue whose name is same as the routing key you pass to the exchange. For example, all the messages with routing key as '12345' will be routed to queue named as '12345' by such an exchange.